# How to update freezed state correctly using future provider?

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-provider, riverpod, flutter-state

Im using riverpod FutureProvider to fetch devices with API calls and try to persist them with StateNotifier in the state with custom state class. If i try to update the loading state i get following error. Any idea?

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Tried to modify a provider while the widget tree was building.
If you are encountering this error, chances are you tried to modify a provider
in a widget life-cycle, such as but not limited to:
- build
- initState
- dispose
- didUpdateWidget
- didChangeDepedencies

Modifying a provider inside those life-cycles is not allowed, as it could
lead to an inconsistent UI state. For example, two widgets could listen to the
same provider, but incorrectly receive different states.


To fix this problem, you have one of two solutions:
- (preferred) Move the logic for modifying your provider outside of a widget
  life-cycle. For example, maybe you could update your provider inside a button's
  onPressed instead.

- Delay your modification, such as by encasuplating the modification
  in a `Future(() {...})`.
  This will perform your update after the widget tree is done building.
```

**state class**

```
@freezed
class DevicePageState<T> with _$DevicePageState {
  const factory DevicePageState.initial() = Initial;
  const factory DevicePageState.loading() = Loading;
  const factory DevicePageState.loaded(AsyncValue<List<Device>> devices) = Loaded;
  const factory DevicePageState.error() = Error;
}
```

**state notifier**

```
abstract class IRepository extends StateNotifier<DevicePageState> {
  IRepository(DevicePageState devicePageState) : super(const DevicePageState.initial());

  Future<void> fetchDevices();
  Future<void> fetchTargetDevice();
  Future<void> updateDevice();
}
```

**repo**

```
class DeviceApiRepository extends IRepository {
  final UPnPDiscoveryService upnpDiscoveryService;
  final Ref ref;

  DeviceApiRepository({required this.ref, required this.upnpDiscoveryService}) : super(const DevicePageState.loading());

  @override
  Future<void> fetchDevices() async {
    try {
      // state = const DevicePageState.loading();
      final devices = ref.watch(upnpDevicesProviderProvider);
      state = DevicePageState.loaded(devices);
    } catch (e) {
      state = const DevicePageState.error();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> fetchTargetDevice() async {
    try {
      state = const DevicePageState.loading();
      final targetDevice = ref.watch(upnpDevicesProviderProvider);
      state = DevicePageState.loaded(targetDevice);
    } catch (e) {
      state = const DevicePageState.error();
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateDevice() async {
    try {
      state = const DevicePageState.loading();
      final devices = ref.watch(upnpDevicesProviderProvider);
      state = DevicePageState.loaded(devices);
    } catch (e) {
      state = const DevicePageState.error();
    }
  }
}
```

The error was thrown in the fetchDevices after i try to reassign state.
Thank you

**Edit:**
I call the fetchDevices method in a build method of the ConsumerWidget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.read(deviceApiRepositoryProvider.notifier).fetchDevices();
    final data = ref.watch(deviceApiRepositoryProvider);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```dart
class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(deviceApiRepositoryProvider);

    const factory DevicePageState.initial() = Initial;
  const factory DevicePageState.loading() = Loading;
  const factory DevicePageState.loaded(AsyncValue<List<Device>> devices) = Loaded;
  const factory DevicePageState.error() = Error;

    return state.when(
      initial: () => ...,
      loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      error: () => Text('Oops, something unexpected happened'),
      loaded: (List<Device> devices) => Text('$devices'),
    );
  }
}
```

Your `fetch` method (or use [Notifier](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/providers/notifier_provider) and `build` method):

```dart
  @override
  Future<void> fetchDevices() async {
    state = const DevicePageState.loading();
    try {
      // you cannot use watch here
      // or, consider using `Notifier<DevicePageState>` with the `build` method
      final devices = ref.read(upnpDevicesProviderProvider);
      state = DevicePageState.loaded(devices);
    } catch (e) {
      state = const DevicePageState.error();
    }
  }
```

Note that you do not need to use `AsyncValue<List<Device>> devices`. Consider using [AsyncNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncNotifierProvider.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The error is still happen when i call the fetchDevices method in the build method. I've try to call it in the initState of a ConsumerStateful widget.. Same error

Comment: try call your method in the initializer of the `DeviceApiRepository` class